# Clip data while reading file into Python with GeoPandas

Tags: python, clip, geopandas, masking, fiona

`Geopandas` is able to read in only part of a file using:

```
roi= geopandas.GeoDataFrame(geometry)
indexed_data = geopandas.read_file("path-to-file", mask=roi)
```

or

```
geopandas.read_file("path-to-file", bbox=(0, 0, 10, 20))
```

However, some of the vector data I want to read extends (far) beyond the bbox / mask as the full line which comes into contact with the bbox / mask is included. To avoid reading superfluous data, I would like to clip the vector while reading it into Python.

Is there a method to read vector data while clipping it by a certain region?

Reading all data and subsequently clipping it to a region would be an option, but is rather avoided since the data set is quite large.

Comment: what do you want to cut? a raster?

Comment: I would like to cut a vector (coastline, hence possibly very long for some regions in the world).

Comment: Define a different bbox or mask for the data you want?

Comment: seems like using ```mask``` parameter is fine? have you tried it tho? did it take long?

Answer (score -1):

Same question, the result with mask only use spatial index(for intersection). So it's fast. If you are considering performance(ignore memory), reading all data and subsequently clipping it may be same.